# Updating based on Condition of Previous Occurrence

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a data frame

```
  stim1 stim2 Chosen Rejected
1:     2     1      2        1
2:     3     2      2        3
3:     3     1      1        3
4:     2     3      3        2
5:     1     3      1        3
```

My objective is at each trial to add a column that specifies whether the stimulus was most recently (in previous trials) Chosen or Rejected.

desired outcome

```
  stim1 stim2 Chosen Rejected     Previous_stim1   Previous_stim2
1:     2     1      2        1        NaN              NaN
2:     3     2      2        3        NaN              Chosen
3:     3     1      1        3        Rejected         Rejected
4:     2     3      3        2        Chosen           Rejected
5:     1     3      1        3        Chosen           Chosen
```

any help will be greatly appreciated!

---

### UPDATE

TarJae had a really helpful suggestion that helped categorize the piece of the dataframe i shared correctly. I didn't mention that it's really part of a larger data frame and for some reason fairly quickly this method stops classifying correctly

```
   stim1 stim2 Chosen Rejected Previous_stim1 Previous_stim2
 1:     2     1      2        1           <NA>           <NA>
 2:     3     2      2        3           <NA>         Chosen
 3:     3     1      1        3       Rejected       Rejected
 4:     2     3      3        2         Chosen       Rejected
 5:     1     3      1        3         Chosen         Chosen
 6:     2     1      1        2         Chosen         Chosen
 7:     2     3      2        3         Chosen         Chosen
 8:     3     1      1        3         Chosen         Chosen
 9:     2     1      2        1         Chosen         Chosen
```

For example, in row 6 stim1==2. Most recently, 2 was rejected (row 4) but the method classified it as chosen.

Any ideas what this happens?

Thank you again for everyones help.

---

**Update 2**

Thank you so much for your help. But say I have also a column with the "outcome".

```
   stim1 stim2 Chosen Rejected outcome Previous_stim 1 Previous_stim 2
1:    15    13     15       13       1            <NA>            <NA>
2:    13    14     14       13       1        Rejected            <NA>
3:    14    15     14       15       1          Chosen          Chosen
4:    14    13     14       13       0          Chosen        Rejected
5:    13    15     13       15       0        Rejected        Rejected
6:    14    15     14       15       1          Chosen        Rejected
7:    15    13     15       13       1        Rejected          Chosen
8:    14    15     14       15       0          Chosen          Chosen

 I want to encode whether it was 
1) most recently  chosen and outcome=1 (can be coded as 1)
2) most recently chosen and outcome=0 (can be coded as 2)
3) most recently rejected and outcome=1 (can be coded as 3)
4) most recently rejected and outcome=0 (can be coded as 4)
```

is there an easy way to modify the code to make that happen?

Desired output

```
  stim1 stim2 Chosen Rejected outcome Previous_stim 1 Previous_stim 2 Left_type right_type
1     2     3      2        3       1            <NA>            <NA>       NaN        NaN
2     1     3      3        1       1            <NA>        Rejected       NaN          3
3     2     1      1        2       1          Chosen        Rejected         1          3
4     1     2      1        2       0          Chosen        Rejected         1          3
5     3     1      3        1       1          Chosen          Chosen         1          2
```

---

**LAST FOLLOW UP**

Finally, I would like to add a column checking whether the chosen stimulus in that previous trial (which I am referencing as the most recent rejected trial for the stim in question) is the same as my current alternative stimulus

For example if have

```
  stim1 stim2 Chosen Rejected     Previous_stim1   Previous_stim2
1:     2     1      2        1        NaN              NaN
2:     3     2      2        3        NaN              Chosen
3:     3     1      1        3        Rejected         Rejected
4:     2     3      3        2        Chosen           Rejected
5:     1     3      1        3        Chosen           Chosen
```

And here is how I would update my table

```
in trial 3, previous_stim1 (i.e 3) was previously rejectedin favor of 2 (from trial 2) and not in favor of 1 (which is the current alternative) and so Current_alternative_left=0. 

 Similarly, previous_stim2 (i.e 1)was previously 
rejected but that was rejected in favor of 2 (from trial 1) 
and so current_alternative_right=0
    
    On the other hand, in trial 4 stim1=2 
was previously chosen relative to the same
```

stimulus as its currently being pitted against (3)
and so current_alternative_right=1

Desired Output

```
stim1 stim2 Chosen Rejected outcome Previous_stim 1 Previous_stim 2 Left_type right_type
1     2     3      2        3       1            <NA>            <NA>       NaN        NaN
2     1     3      3        1       1            <NA>        Rejected       NaN          3
3     2     1      1        2       1          Chosen        Rejected         1          3
4     1     2      1        2       0          Chosen        Rejected         1          3
5     3     1      3        1       1          Chosen          Chosen         1          2

Current_alternative_left    Current_alternative_right
NaN                           NaN
NaN                           0
0                             0 
1                             0
1                             0
```

i am new to data.table but i tried to copy ThomasisCoding function to return this as well with

```
 h <- function(stim, cr) {
            stim_chosen <- rep(NA,length(stim))
            for (k in seq_along(stim)[-1]) {
                  
                  ind <- which(cr[1:(k - 1), , drop = FALSE] == stim[k], arr.ind = TRUE)
                  if (length(ind)) {
                        stim_chosen[k] <- stim[tail(ind,1)[,"row"]]
                        
                  }
            }
            stim_chosen 
      }


setDT(df)[  ,
                      paste0("Chosen_Last", 1:2) := lapply(
                            .(stim1, stim2),
                            h,
                            cr = cbind(Chosen,Rejected)
                      )
                      ]
```

though this is not quite giving me the correct answer. Anyone know where i am going wrong?

Comment: Why is `Previous_stim1` row2 `NaN?`

Comment: because there are no previous instances of it being Chosen or rejected

Comment: Sorry, but just to get the logic. `stim1` row1 =2. Is this not the previous instance of `stim1` row2=3?

Comment: when i look at previous instances im only checking in the chosen and rejected columns.  So stim1 in row 2==3 and 3 was never presented yet and so its NaN. But stim2==2 was Chosen in the previous trial and so Previous_stim2=chosen

Comment: So, `Previous_stim1[5]` would be `Rejected`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **Update 2**

```
setDT(df)[
  ,
  paste0("Previous_stim", 1:2) := lapply(
    .(stim1, stim2),
    f,
    cr = cbind(Chosen, Rejected)
  )
][
  ,
  paste0(c("left", "right"), "type") := lapply(.SD, function(x) 2 * (x == "Rejected") + 2 - outcome),
  .SDcols = patterns("Previous")
][]
```

gives

```
   stim1 stim2 Chosen Rejected outcome Previous_stim1 Previous_stim2 lefttype
1:     2     1      2        1       1           <NA>           <NA>       NA
2:     3     2      2        3       1           <NA>         Chosen       NA
3:     3     1      1        3       1       Rejected       Rejected        3
4:     2     3      3        2       0         Chosen       Rejected        2
5:     1     3      1        3       0         Chosen         Chosen        2
6:     2     1      1        2       1       Rejected         Chosen        3
7:     2     3      2        3       1       Rejected       Rejected        3
8:     3     1      1        3       0       Rejected         Chosen        4
9:     2     1      2        1       0         Chosen         Chosen        2
   righttype
1:        NA
2:         1
3:         3
4:         4
5:         2
6:         1
7:         3
8:         2
9:         2
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(stim1 = c(2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L),
    stim2 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L), Chosen = c(2L,
    2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), Rejected = c(1L, 3L, 3L,
    2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L), outcome = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

---

As per your update, you can try the following code by defining a custom function `f`

```
f <- function(stim, cr) {
  res <- rep(NA, length(stim))
  for (k in seq_along(stim)[-1]) {
    ind <- which(cr[1:(k - 1), , drop = FALSE] == stim[k], arr.ind = TRUE)
    if (length(ind)) {
      res[k] <- colnames(cr)[tail(ind[, "col"][order(ind[, "row"])], 1)]
    }
  }
  res
}

setDT(df)[
  ,
  paste("Previous_stim", 1:2) := lapply(
    .(stim1, stim2),
    f,
    cr = cbind(Chosen, Rejected)
  )
][]
```

and you will see

```
> setDT(df)[, paste("Previous_stim",1:2) := lapply(.(stim1,stim2),f, cr = cbind(Chosen, Rejected))][]
   stim1 stim2 Chosen Rejected Previous_stim 1 Previous_stim 2
1:     2     1      2        1            <NA>            <NA>
2:     3     2      2        3            <NA>          Chosen
3:     3     1      1        3        Rejected        Rejected
4:     2     3      3        2          Chosen        Rejected
5:     1     3      1        3          Chosen          Chosen
6:     2     1      1        2        Rejected          Chosen
7:     2     3      2        3        Rejected        Rejected
8:     3     1      1        3        Rejected          Chosen
9:     2     1      2        1          Chosen          Chosen
```

Comment: I added the follow up question to your solution in update 2, since my eventual objective is to also encode what the outcome was. I am not yet familiar with data.frame- would I need to create four distinct functions for that?

thanks again!

Comment: thank you again for all of your help! i updated the question with one last piece of it- wondering if there is an easy way to return that additional information (where the pair is repeated and where its not)

Comment: @user15791858 I guess this is the easiest way I can do so far ...

Comment: i made an attempt to use your function to return the last stimulus (see latest update) but it seems like im a bit off- any idea what im doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that was generated with the help of ThomasIsCoding [Check if value of column A is present in the same row or previous rows of column B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68943645/check-if-value-of-column-a-is-present-in-the-same-row-or-previous-rows-of-column/68943766#68943645):Here are also additional answers which are adequate for your solution! You could change and adapt which one fits for you. I chose the first one provided by ThomasIsCoding.

The main task was to check the value in all previous rows of an other column

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(x = replace(rep(NA, length(Chosen)), match(stim1, lag(Chosen)) <= seq_along(stim1), "Chosen"),
           y = replace(rep(NA, length(Rejected)), match(stim1, lag(Rejected)) <= seq_along(stim1), "Rejected"),
           a = replace(rep(NA, length(Chosen)), match(stim2, lag(Chosen)) <= seq_along(stim2), "Chosen"),
           b = replace(rep(NA, length(Rejected)), match(stim2, lag(Rejected)) <= seq_along(stim2), "Rejected"),
           Previous_stim1 = coalesce(x, y),
           Previous_stim2 = coalesce(a, b)) %>% 
    select(stim1, stim2, Chosen, Rejected, Previous_stim1, Previous_stim2)
```

```
   stim1 stim2 Chosen Rejected Previous_stim1 Previous_stim2
1:     2     1      2        1           <NA>           <NA>
2:     3     2      2        3           <NA>         Chosen
3:     3     1      1        3       Rejected       Rejected
4:     2     3      3        2         Chosen       Rejected
5:     1     3      1        3         Chosen         Chosen
```

Comment: Nice one, man. Haven't tried this one yet, but I thought of "something using `row_number()`".

Comment: yup, this answer uses row_number https://stackoverflow.com/a/68944025/4663008 and another answer there uses rowwise to figure it out too.

Comment: thank you tarjae this is super helpful. The piece of the dataframe I shared works perfectly but for some reason as it goes on it no longer classifies correctly. I edited the original question with the output of your suggested script. 

Do you know why this happens?
again, thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to correct the desired outcome in the above table. But it looks like you are looking for the `lag` verb which can helpfully solve this when used alongside `if_else`:

```
library(dplyr)

tbl <- tibble(stim1 = c(2,3,3,2,1), stim2 = c(1,2,1,3,3), 
              chosen = c(2,2,1,3,1), rejected = c(1,3,3,2,3))

tbl %>% 
mutate(Previous_stim1 = if_else(lag(tbl$chosen) == lag(stim1), "Chosen", "Rejected")) %>%
mutate(Previous_stim2 = if_else(lag(tbl$chosen) == lag(stim2), "Chosen", "Rejected"))
```