# Check if value of column A is present in the same row or previous rows of column B

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, match, tidyverse

I have this dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(A = 1:5, B = c(1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

  A B
1 1 1
2 2 5
3 3 2
4 4 3
5 5 3
```

I would like to get this result:

```
  A B Result
1 1 1      B
2 2 5   <NA>
3 3 2   <NA>
4 4 3   <NA>
5 5 3      B
```

Strategy:

1. Check if `A==B` then assign `B` to new column `Result` if not `NA`.
2. But do this also for all ***PREVIOUS*** rows of `B`.

**AIM:**

I want to learn how to check if a certain value of column `A` say in row 5
is in the previous rows of column `B` (eg. row 1-4).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope the following code fits your general cases

```
transform(
  df,
  Result = replace(rep(NA, length(B)), match(A, B) <= seq_along(A), "B")
)
```

which gives

```
  A B Result
1 1 1      B
2 2 5   <NA>
3 3 2   <NA>
4 4 3   <NA>
5 5 3      B
```

Comment: does this solution assume A is always 1,2,3 ... ?

Comment: @ArthurYip No, it can be any numeric vector.

Comment: Oh I see, if a match is in a row <= the seq_along result (the row number), then, it allows "B" to replace NA.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding This looks very good. I am struggling to implement it to my use case. give me 5 more minutes. please.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding. Thank you very much. With your help I was able to solve this task <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68940682/updating-based-on-condition-of-previous-occurrence/68944022#68944022>

Comment: Can this be golfed to `"B"[NA^(!match(df$A, df$B) <= seq_along(df$A))]`?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `dplyr::rowwise` approach:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(result = ifelse(A %in% .[seq(cur_group_rows()),]$B, "B", NA))

#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       A     B result
#>   <int> <int> <chr> 
#> 1     1     1 B     
#> 2     2     5 <NA>  
#> 3     3     2 <NA>  
#> 4     4     3 <NA>  
#> 5     5     3 B
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you TimTeaFan. This is also very good!

Comment: Maybe you should think about a verb for this procedure to implement in your package?

Answer (score 2):

Just some minor changes to @ThomasIsCoding's answer to make it dplyr. Slightly more laid-out to be easier to read, in my opinion.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(A = 1:5, B = c(1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
match(df$A, df$B)
#> [1]  1  3  4 NA  2
df %>% mutate(Result = if_else(match(A, B) <= row_number(), 
                               "B", 
                               NA_character_))
#>   A B Result
#> 1 1 1      B
#> 2 2 5   <NA>
#> 3 3 2   <NA>
#> 4 4 3   <NA>
#> 5 5 3      B
```

Created on 2021-08-26 by the reprex package (v1.0.0)

Comment: This looks very fine. I will try it on my use case. A similar approach failed in my case. But I will see now.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   mutate(Result = map_chr(row_number(), ~ case_when(A[.x] %in% B[seq(.x)]~ "B")))
```

-output

```
 A B Result
1 1 1      B
2 2 5   <NA>
3 3 2   <NA>
4 4 3   <NA>
5 5 3      B
```