# How to convert dataframe with 3 columns into matrix in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

How to convert dataframe with 3 columns into a matrix in R?

- cols - unique values of the first column
- rows - unique values of the second column

The first 2 columns are string and the 3rd column is numeric.
need to calculate the `mean` of 3rd column according to the names matching

example

```
# My data frame as like follows
B=c("B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2")
A=c("A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2")
count=1:8
df = data.frame(B,A,count)
df
   B  A count
1 B1 A1     1
2 B1 A1     2
3 B1 A2     3
4 B1 A2     4
5 B2 A1     5
6 B2 A1     6
7 B2 A2     7
8 B2 A2     8
```

the converted matrix should like as follows. Values of the matrix should be the mean of according to

```
    A1  A2
B1 1.5 3.5
B2 5.5 7.5
```

I have tried many ways but didn't work any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `tapply` from `base R` (no packages needed and it returns the format specified in the OP's post)

```
out <- tapply(df$count, df[1:2], FUN = mean)
names(dimnames(out)) <- NULL
```

-output

```
 out
    A1  A2
B1 1.5 3.5
B2 5.5 7.5

 is.matrix(out)
[1] TRUE
```

---

or another option is `xtabs` from `base R` and divide

```
xtabs(count ~B + A, df)/2
    A
B     A1  A2
  B1 1.5 3.5
  B2 5.5 7.5
```

---

Or may also use `aggregate` with `reshape` from `base R`

```
reshape(aggregate(count ~ B + A, df, mean), idvar = 'B',
      direction = 'wide', timevar = 'A')
   B count.A1 count.A2
1 B1      1.5      3.5
2 B2      5.5      7.5
```

---

Or we may also use `acast` from `reshape2`

```
library(reshape2)
acast(df, B ~ A, mean)
    A1  A2
B1 1.5 3.5
B2 5.5 7.5
```

Comment: out <- tapply(df$count, df[1:2], FUN = mean) is good. But how to avoid region A & B in the matrix?

Comment: Assign the `names(dimnames(out)) <- NULL` updated

Answer (score 4):

An alternative way could be:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- df %>% 
    group_by(B, A) %>% 
    summarize(mean = mean(count), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
    pivot_wider(
        names_from = A,
        values_from = mean
    ) %>% 
    column_to_rownames("B") %>% as.matrix(df)

class(df1)
```

output:

```
    A1  A2
B1 1.5 3.5
B2 5.5 7.5
> class(df1)
[1] "matrix" "array"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tidyr::pivot_wider` -

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = A, values_from = count, values_fn = mean)

#   B      A1    A2
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 B1      1.5   3.5
#2 B2      5.5   7.5
```

If you need output as matrix -

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = A, values_from = count, values_fn = mean) %>%
  column_to_rownames('B') %>%
  as.matrix()

#    A1  A2
#B1 1.5 3.5
#B2 5.5 7.5
```

---

And the same in `data.table` -

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), B~A, value.var = 'count', fun.aggregate = mean)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `igraph`

```
graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = FALSE) %>%
  simplify(edge.attr.comb = "mean") %>%
  get.incidence(types = names(V(.)) %in% df$A, attr = "count")
```

which gives

```
    A1  A2
B1 1.5 3.5
B2 5.5 7.5
```

Comment: HI ThomasIsCoding. Dear Thomas, Need your help again <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68943645/check-if-value-of-column-a-is-present-in-the-same-row-or-previous-rows-of-column/68943766#68943645>. The OP updated the question. Could you please review your answer and maybe have a suggestion for the new task.

Comment: @TarJae I added a solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/68977317/12158757 based on OP's update. You can see if that is the thing you want.